# Adding an rmic task to an sbt project

Tags: java, scala, ant, sbt, rmi

I have a java project that I am adding some scala code to. Previously I used ant to build the project and am moving to using sbt. In the ant build file was an rmic task to build the RMI Stub classes in the project. This is a task that comes directly with ant. Has anyone used a similar task in sbt or do they know how I could define one?

Thanks
Des

Comment: RMI stubs can be generated automatically at runtime. There's no need to run `rmic`.

Comment: YOu should look into the protobuf plugins for examples of how to do what you want, as they operate similarly.  The basic gist is that you want a `resourceGenerators in Compile += <my task>`.